# python 2 code VS python 3 ,zoho crm api

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, urllib, zoho

i'm tring to use python 3 insted of python 2 in ZOHO CRM API.

in python 2 the code that works is:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
module_name = 'Leads'
authtoken = '[authtoken]'
valueToSeek = 'test'
params = {'authtoken':authtoken,'scope':'crmapi','criteria':'(((Last 
Name:'+valueToSeek+')'}
final_URL = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/searchRecords"
data = urllib.urlencode(params)
request = urllib2.Request(final_URL,data)
response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
xml_response = response.read()
```

in python 3 the code that doesn't works is:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
import urllib.parse
module_name = 'Leads'
authtoken = '[authtoken]'
valueToSeek = 'test'
params = {'authtoken':authtoken,'scope':'crmapi','criteria':'(((Last 
Name:'+valueToSeek+')'}
final_URL = 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/Leads/searchRecords'
data = urllib.parse.urlencode(params)
request = urllib.request.Request(final_URL,data)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
xml_response = response.read()
print (xml_response)
```

i get this:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Darda_000/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36-32/zohoTestPY3.py", line 12, in 
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(request)   File "C:\Users\Darda_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)   File "C:\Users\Darda_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 524, in open
    req = meth(req)   File "C:\Users\Darda_000\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 1248, in do_request_
    raise TypeError(msg) TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.

What is my mistake?

Comment: data is a string, not `bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object`

Comment: TNX, how do i fix it?